# Sustained growth in Ramsey model

Tags: macroeconomics, endogenous-growth, balanced-growth, ramsey

It is known that in the classical Solow model that if we use CES production function instead of Cobb Douglas function, it is possible to have sustained growth if the substitutability is larger than 1.

However is it possible to achieve sustained growth in Ramsey model with a CES production function consisting of just labour and capital?